# How to use "registry" scope in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to have a try with the new "registry" scope in ESB 4.9.0, but when I set up a simple proxy with the provided example in property mediator documentation, it cannot be saved and reports an error.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2015-09-24 15:30:21,085] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin} -  Unable to save changes made for the proxy service : test_property. Restored the existing proxy... :: Only 'axis2' or 'transport' or 'axis2-client' or 'default' or 'operation' values are allowed for attribute scope for a property mediator, Unsupported scope registry {org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.service.ProxyServiceAdmin}
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Only 'axis2' or 'transport' or 'axis2-client' or 'default' or 'operation' values are allowed for attribute scope for a property mediator, Unsupported scope registry
```

Here is the proxy

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test_property"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property  name="conf:/Resource/foo" value="Sample Property Content" scope="registry"/>       
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I am not sure if I need to set up some configuration first? I downloaded a new esb 4.9.0 package, and run separately. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve properties from within the registry by using the registry scope.

```
<property name="fromRegistryToDefault" expression="get-property('registry','registryPath@propertyName')"/>
```

[Documentation of retrieving properties from registry](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/XPath+Extension+Functions#XPathExtensionFunctions-registryscope)

But I don't think you can store new properties into the registry store directly from a Proxy inSequence. Do you have any documentation about that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've checked the documentation from docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490 again, the content related to "registry" scope in "Property mediator" is removed. Previously it said, WSO2 can set property to persist values in the registry in proxy configuration (with example, but not work).

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.9 does not allow this value for the scope of a property mediator.

Download the ESB 5.0.0 and you will see that your proxy works perfectly.

You can store in "registry" scope in this version.

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test_property"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="conf:/Resource/foo"
                   scope="registry"
                   type="STRING"
                   value="Sample Property Content"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```